# How to replace text inside [{ }] brackets in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

How to replace text inside  [{ }] brackets in jquery including brackets?
Tried following regex

```
var text = "Hi [{FName}{LName}]";
text.replace(/\[{(.*?)}]/g,'contactname');

text.replace(/[{.*}]/, 'contactname');
```

Expcted Output: "Hi contactname";

Comment: What is your expected output for your code?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMarshall , expected output added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the inner part but keep the `[{}]` you can use `.replace` with a callback function replacing just the inner capture group 1 (with anything you want):

```js
const regex = /\[{(.*?)}\]/g;
const str = `some text [{xxxxxx}] more text
bt [{yyyyy}] ct
no match here`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (group1) return "[{}]"
    else m;
});

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Otherwise just use `var result = str.replace(/\[{(.*?)}\]/g, '[{}]');`